# How to initialize a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global

I have a jquery as below :

```
var ttl = 0;


$(document).ready(function(){

$('.click').click(function() {
alert(ttl);
var ttl = $('#t1').val() + $('#t2').val();
alert(ttl);

});
});
```

And the HTML :

```
    <a href="#" class="click">Click Me</a>
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />
```

Now clicking on `click` link alerts `undefined`, but I am expecting to alert a `0`. How can I initialize the `ttl` variable to `0` globally ?

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6P85/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you've *shadowed* your `ttl` variable by declaring it within the function. Remove the `var` in front of `ttl` in the function.

That may surprise you, because your initial `alert` is *above* the `var ttl;` line in that function. That's because in JavaScript, `var` declarations are, in effect, "hoisted" (moved to the top of the function). [More in this article on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html), but basically this:

```
function foo() {
   var a;

   doSomething();

   var b = 42;

   doSomethingElse();
}
```

is actually interpreted like this:

```
function foo() {
   var a;
   var b;

   doSomething();

   b = 42;

   doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: I made it as before now.sorry

Answer (score 0):

Don't do like this

```
var ttl = $('#t1').val() + $('#t2').val();
```

If it is initialize one don't use `var` again

```
ttl = $('#t1').val() + $('#t2').val();
```

For more check this article of **[Variable Scope](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-3/variable-scope)**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var global1 = "I'm a global!";
var global2 = "So am I!";

// other js-file
function testGlobal () {
    alert(global1);
}
```